# if else gives fatal error

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to check whether entered username already existed in my database or not. if not then add up to database. I made function which gives correct result if username existed. The problem is when i entered a name which does not exist in my database the apps stops. When i entered a name which existed in database it Toast me. 
Kindly tell me why apps get stopped.

I select database with this query,

```
// Check if user already exist or not
    public Cursor isAlreadyExist(String name){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + NAME_USER + " FROM " + TABLE_USER
                + " WHERE " + NAME_USER + "=" + name, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Function to get username from database,

```
// Check if user already exist
     public String isAlreadyExist(String name) {
         Cursor cursor = db.isAlreadyExist(name);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         String names = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.NAME_USER));
        return names;
    }
```

using of this function,

```
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String name = username.getText().toString();
                    if(name.equals(isAlreadyExist(name))){
                        //db.addNewUser(username.getText().toString(), util.computeSHAHash(password.getText().toString()));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "already", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat output. It is hard to guess where an error is with no logs.

Comment: nothing is to be caught also by try and catch block

Comment: no message shown in log cat

Comment: Then what do you mean your app stops? If your app crashes there would be logcat output, if it does not crash then explain better what exactly happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the **cursor.moveToFirst();** when cursor is empty, need to check the cursor size if it is greater than zero then we need to moveToFirst. Update this method and check.

Function to get username from database,

```
public String isAlreadyExist(String name)
    {
        String names = "";
        Cursor cursor = db.isAlreadyExist(name);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            names = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.NAME_USER));
        }

        return names;
    }
```

Comment: @bc120201817 Zohaib Siddiq Is this solution fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1.**Check cursor is null or not before using moveToFirst() function**

2.**Initilize the String**

Write this function

```
public String isAlreadyExist(String name) {
     Cursor cursor = db.isAlreadyExist(name);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     String names = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.NAME_USER));
    return names;
}
```

as

```
 public String isAlreadyExist(String name) {
     Cursor cursor = db.isAlreadyExist(name);
     String names="";
     if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
     names = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.NAME_USER));
     }else{
        names = "User does not exist";
     }
   return names;
}
```